# How can I get Console.Write() to print multiple string variables?

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

I'm having a hard time getting my console.write() function to print multiple strings on the console. It only prints the first one. Am I missing some sort of syntax ? `

```
//Prompts the user for the first adjective

Console.WriteLine(@"Enter an adjective, (a word that decribes a noun,i.e blue, silly or outrageous).");
string firstAdjective = Console.ReadLine();

//Prompts the user for a second adjective

Console.WriteLine(@"Enter a second adjective please...");
string secondAdjective = Console.ReadLine();


//Prompts the user for a third adjective
Console.WriteLine(@"One more adjective please.");
string thirdAdjective = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write ("Your Adjectives are " firstAdjective, secondAdjective, thirdAdjective);`
```

After this execution, the console only prints out the firstAdjective.

Comment: This code isn't syntactically correct. `Console.Write ("Your Adjectives are " firstAdjective, secondAdjective, thirdAdjective);` would not compile.

Comment: Here are three options: [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0), and [How to concatenate multiple strings (C# Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings)

Comment: Try `Console.Write($"Your adjectives are {firstAdjective}, {secondAdjective}, {thirdAdjective}");`  string-interpolation is much nicer than the old approaches.

Comment: @DanielMann it will compile, the OP is just unwittingly using [this function signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-7.0#system-console-write(system-string-system-object-system-object-system-object)).  He is very unlucky

Comment: @Jake with a missing `,` between the string literal and the variable `firstAdjective`? I don't think so

Comment: Ah good call @DanielMann, my bad.

Comment: THANK YOU all SO Much !!!, I just got into this subject last night and I was feeling a bit flustered. Trying to pick back up on what I tried to learn years ago.